# dropdown list selected index changed razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using razor view engine(cshtml) outside of mvc framework. i.e only view is converted to cshtml format.

I make all database calls using webmatrix and construct cshtml view.

Although, now i want to fire dropdown list selected change event which will set or fill contents of another dropdown list on the same page.

Currently I use dropdown list using

```
@HTML.DropdownList("ID",List)
```

on the selectedindex change of dropdown, i wish to check it's value and then decide on whether or not to populate second dropdown.

How can I do it in this scenario? Remember, no mvc framework, hence no access to models or mvc specific methods.

Comment: If I understand your problem, Why don't use Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

when the dropdown list is rendered in the browser, it simply becomes a HTML tag and you can use vanilla javascript or frameworks like jQuery to check the item selected and load the next dropdown.

Sample:

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
```